# Conceptual: Web-enabled C# application

Tags: c#

I am struggling with a C# Website design concept.

Say I have a the need for an application that increments an integer continuously all day (simple representation of any continuous long running process).  I need to write a website that would allow me (and other users) to log on, view the current value, ideally witness it updating, possibly interact with it by, say, resetting it, and then log off, leaving the process running.

Can I write this as one website, or would I have to write a website to serve pages and separate application to do the continuous work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would have the "work" be some kind of Windows Service that can be interacted with (through database state, or directly through some transport mechanism, WCF, Message Queue, whatever). The website would then just talk to the existing service and do what it needs to do (get status, update etc).

Comment: +1 Websites are inherently stateless.  Designing a website to persist it's state indefinitely is bound to be full of problems.

Comment: Thank you, that has cleared up my concern.  I also have to implement a stock-ticker type update, and again, that looks like something that a separate process should run, and then the site should either poll or use server-side events for updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could have one webpage as there would be no need to serve multiple pages. The page could read the counter value from internal memory, a database or a web service which is continuously updating (Maybe add an AjaxUpdate Panel to show it ticking up).  You could then code a function such as `ResetCounter()` which would connect to the database / web service and reset the count.

Comment: Apologies, the 'updating integer' example was a simplification, to illustrate the design problem only.  Your reference to using a web service is valid though, I will look into pursuing that route, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with storing the integer in an [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant database, like SQL Server? Then you can interact with a web application you build, right? Seems to be the ideal way of handling a shared object like this integer value. ACID compliance means the integer will survive a hardware failure pretty well, you can log activities about who is tweaking the integer, etc. Writing your own service that keeps the value in shared memory probably doesn't offer a huge advantage compared to transacting with a database.

Comment: The integer value was only an example to illustrate the simplest task I could think of.  The actual work involved is a FIX client connection.  The FIX connection is established at the start of the day, and is maintained throughout the day, heartbeating periodically.  The web-client hops on, sends an order, views orders or trades, and hops off.  Looks like I should not attempt to get the website to do too much, I should keep the site slim, and outboard the continuous connection, and message between the two.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of routes you could take.  I would separate this into 3 different roles:

- State Management: This layers simply stores the state of the counter or work. Determine what type of data store will be used (such as SQL Server)
- Worker: This layer is the 'worker' role, responsible for incrementing the counter or whatever work needs to be done.  This could be a Windows Service as others have posted, but I would probably opt for Windows Workflow exposed as a WCF Service.  It would be much easier to manage the 'worker' this way and offers a more scalable solution.
- UI: The next layer would the actual website, such as an ASP.NET MVC application, which could subscribe to the service and make various method calls.

See Workflow Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456797

Comment: Good points, separation of roles seems very sensible.  Thanks for your help.